# Dockerized Django: how to manage sql scripts in migrations?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, database-migration, devops

Fairly new to **Docker**, I am trying to add the execution of a custom *sql script* (triggers and functions) to Django's migration process and I am starting to feel a bit lost. Overall, What I am trying to achieve follows this pretty [clear tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/). In this tutorial, migrations are achieved by the execution of an entry point script. In the Dockerfile:

```
# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/my_app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Here is the **entrypoint.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

# tried several with and without combinations
python manage.py flush --no-input 
python manage.py makemigrations my_app 
python manage.py migrate

exec "$@"
```

So far so good. Turning to the question of integrating the execution of **custom sql scripts** in the migration process, most articles I read ([this one](https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2016/09/17/executing-custom-sql-in-django-migration) for instance) recommend to create an empty migration to add the execution of sql statements. Here is what I have in 
`my_app/migrations/0001_initial_data.py`

```
import os
from django.db import migrations, connection

def load_data_from_sql(filename):
    file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../sql/', filename)
    sql_statement = open(file_path).read()
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql_statement)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('my_app', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(load_data_from_sql('my_app_base.sql'))
    ]
```

As stated by **dependencies**, this step depends on the initial one (`0001_initial.py`):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Unpayed',
            fields=[
etc etc
```

[**The Issue**] However, even when I try to manually migrate (`docker-compose exec web python manage.py makemigrations my_app`), I get the following error because the *db in the postgresql container is **empty***:

```
File "/usr/src/my_app/my_app/migrations/0001_initial_data.py", line 21, in Migration
    migrations.RunPython(load_data_from_sql('my_app_base.sql'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
....
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
    django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
```

[**What I do not understand**] However, when I log in the container, remove `0001_initial_data.py` and run `./entrypoint.sh`, everything works like a charm and tables are created. I can add `0001_initial_data.py` manually later on, run entrypoint.sh angain and have my functions. Same when I remove this file before running `docker-compose up -d --build`: tables are created.

I feel like I am missing some obvious way and easier around trying integrate sql script migrations in this canonical way. All I need is this script to be run after 0001_initial migration is over. How would you do it?

[**edit**] docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: ./my_app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python /usr/src/my_app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./my_app/:/usr/src/my_app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY='o@@xO=jrd=p0^17svmYpw!22-bnm3zz*%y(7=j+p*t%ei-4pi!'
      - SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
      - SQL_DATABASE=postgres
      - SQL_USER=postgres
      - SQL_PASSWORD=N0tTh3D3favlTpAssw0rd
      - SQL_HOST=db
      - SQL_PORT=5432
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:10.5-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ 

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

django:2.2
python:3.7

Comment: Why are you running `makemigrations` in your Docker file? Is `my_app/migrations/0001_initial.py` checked in?

Comment: "checked in"? You mean, in the container after I `docker-compose up`? Yes it is. And about why `makemigrations` is in the entrypoint? To be completely honest with you, since I find this "create an empty migration to execute custom sql during migration" trick pretty confusing, just to figure out whether it changed something. I thought that `makemigrations` had to be run before `migrate`

Comment: „Checked in“ as in „checked in to version control“. Or in other words, does the migration `0001_initial` exist *before* you `docker-compose up`?

Comment: Yes it does. It is in my source files before I `docker-compose up` (if I am getting your point correctly)

Comment: please share your compose file. also what version of python and django?

Comment: Here it is, @Dap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**The easiest way I could find**] I simply disentangled django migrations from the creation of custom functions in the DB. Migration are run first so that the tables exists when creating the functions. Here is the **entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

python manage.py flush --no-input
python manage.py migrate

# add custom sql functions to db 
cat my_app/sql/my_app_base.sql | python manage.py dbshell

python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

exec "$@"
```

Keep in mind that `manage.py dbshell` requires a `postgresql-client` to run. I just needed to add it in the **Dockerfile**:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.7-alpine

...........

# install psycopg2
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add postgresql-dev postgresql-client\
    && pip install psycopg2 \
    && apk del build-deps
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue has to do with you naming the migration file and manually making your dependencies with the same prefix "0001" The reason I say this is because when you do reverse migrations, you simply can just reference the prefix. IE if you wanted to go from your 7th migration to your 6th migration. The command looks like this `python manage.py migrate my_app 0006` Either way, I would try deleting and creating a new migration file via `python manage.py makemigrations my_app --empty` and moving your code into that file.  This should also write the dependencies for you.

The error message alongside the test you ran with adding he migration file after is indicative of the issue though. Some how initial migrations aren't running before the other one.  I would also try dropping your DB as it may have persisted some bad state `./manage.py sqlflush`

Comment: I just tried renaming the file into `0002_create_custom_functions.py` (manually and with `makemigrations --empty`) but the problem  remains. The only way I could have the table is by only letting `0001_initial.py` when I build. After each attempt, I drop the DB by `docker-compose down -v`. I am a bit confused about the `flush --no-input` and `migrate` command in `entrypoint.sh`. Am I right to assume that all the migrations in /my_app/migrations should be run by `migrate`?

Comment: Do you think of an easier way to execute this script afterwark (outside of the classical migrations process)? the app's cointainer does not have psql but the db's does. Maybe send the sql script from **app** to **db**, log into it and run it (like I would do manually). I noticed that `manage.py` has some kind of **dbshell**. Any chance I could run the script through it?

Comment: so a few things. the way i do things is i write a bootscript. lets say `boot.sh`. I put all migrate and runserver in there. i do not put makemigrations in that bootscript as I run it that manually an commit the migration files to the repo. and instead of having all those commands in teh docker file i have it as a compose as command `command: bootprod.sh` bootprod consists of ```pip install -r requirements.txt
python3 manage.py migrate && python3 manage.py runserver```